# Why doesn't this wheel scroll function run in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to click on the next or previous `li` in a fixed element based on the wheel delta. It's working well in IE and Chrome, but not in Firefox.

```
var itemisMoving=false;
function scrollControls() {
    $(document).bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(event, delta) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (itemisMoving) return;
        navigateTo();
    });
    function navigateTo(e){
        itemisMoving = true;
        var evt = window.event || e
        evt = evt.originalEvent ? evt.originalEvent : evt;
        var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail*(-40) : evt.wheelDelta;
        var itemcurslide = $('.itemw3 ul li.current');
        if(delta > 0) {
            itemcurslide.prev('li').click();
        }
        else{
            itemcurslide.next('li').click();
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            itemisMoving=false;
        },1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`MozMousePixelScroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/MozMousePixelScroll) like this.

```
$(document).bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll", function(event, delta) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (itemisMoving) return;
    navigateTo();
 });
```